# How to add type attribute in PHP SoapClient request

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap, xsd

I need to consum a SOAP service using an instance of SoapClient in PHP.

It throws this validation error:

> +"ValidationError": "cvc-type.2: The type definition cannot be
>   abstract for element ns1:risk."

How should I add the `type` attribute to the array, like this (the first line, the type definition):

```
<xs1:risk xsi:type="xs:Car">
    <xs:base7>
        <xs:base7code>00054030014</xs:base7code>
    </xs:base7>
    <xs:plate>8726CJR</xs:plate>
    <xs:matriculationDate>2003-06-15</xs:matriculationDate>
    <xs:purchaseDate>2003-06-15</xs:purchaseDate>
    <xs:postalCode>03550</xs:postalCode>
    <xs:town>SANT JOAN D'ALACANT</xs:town>
    <xs:trailer>false</xs:trailer>
    <xs:garageType>10</xs:garageType>
    <xs:yearKilometers>28</xs:yearKilometers>
    <xs:habitualDriver>
        <xs1:identificationType>2</xs1:identificationType>
        <xs1:identification>85858585E</xs1:identification>
        <xs1:birthDate>1978-11-09</xs1:birthDate>
        <xs1:gender>1</xs1:gender>
        <xs1:personPermissionDate>1997-03-02</xs1:personPermissionDate>
        <xs1:personExpeditionZone>1</xs1:personExpeditionZone>
        <xs1:personMaritalStatus>3</xs1:personMaritalStatus>
    </xs:habitualDriver>
    <xs:owner>
        <xs1:identificationType>2</xs1:identificationType>
        <xs1:identification>85858585E</xs1:identification>
    </xs:owner>
</xs1:risk>
```

Comment: You can manipulate DOM elements http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: "like this" like what?

Comment: Sorry. I'll clarify... I need to construct an array with attributes (this is important, as seen in the first line in the code). If it is not possible, the other way would be construct the xml and then convert to array... the serverside is a WSDL. Any help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This script converts your xml file in to array

```
class DaneParser 
 {
    public $arrayAttributes = array();
    public $attrName;

    public function __construct($xml) 
    {
        $this->parser = xml_parser_create();
        xml_set_object($this->parser, $this);
        xml_parser_set_option($this->parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
        xml_set_element_handler($this->parser, "startElement", "endElement");
        xml_set_character_data_handler($this->parser, "characterData");
        xml_parse($this->parser, $xml);
    }

    function startElement($parser, $name, $attributes) 
    {
         $name = explode(':',$name);
         $this->attrName = $name[1];
    }


    function endElement($parser, $name) 
    {

    }

    function characterData($parser, $data) 
    {
        if(!isset($this->arrayAttributes[$this->attrName]))
            $this->arrayAttributes[$this->attrName] = $data;
    }

}//END class `enter code here`

//Open xml file
$xml = file_get_contents("xml1.xml");   

//run sax
$pp = new DaneParser($xml);

//Print array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($pp->arrayAttributes);
echo '</pre>';
```